# How can I say something is working (as in, not broken)?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

For example, this sentence:

> My furnace works

would be one of

> Furnus meus [some verb]
>   Furnus meus [some adjective] est (i.e. "my furnace is working")

What could I put in for either the verb or the adjective? Ideally, what word has versions that I could put in for both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Living Latinists say, *Furnus meus munere fungitur.* I've seen no classical attestation of this use applied to objects rather than people, so it's probably a modern adaptation, but I just got back from a living Latin conference where several people said it.

I suppose you could also say *Furnus non deficit*.

In neither of these cases is there a suitable adjective, as far as I can tell. You could use *munifex* for the former, but that of course is really a noun describing a particular kind of Roman soldier.

Comment: Shouldn't that be *munifunx* or something, if it comes from *fungi* instead of *facere*?

Comment: One would think so, but munifex seems to be the attested word: http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2037239 — it was the lowest rank in the Roman army. The entry also mentions a verb *muniafacio*, but there's no entry for it.